# Not explicitly specifying instances of a type in coq

Tags: coq, set-theory

I'm interested in trying my hand at constructing set theory using Coq. I would like to define a type `sets` without specifying what its members are, and a function mapping two sets to a Prop

`Definition elem (s1 s1 : sets) : Prop.`

I would then make the axioms of set theory hypotheses, and express theorems as (for example)

`Theorem : ZFC -> (forall s : sets, ~ elem s s).`

However, the syntax above doesn't work. Is this idea something that can be done in Coq? Is there a better way to accomplish this goal in Coq? I am very new to Coq, so I apologize if there is an obvious way of doing this that I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give names to theorems. And for postulating things, use `Parameter` and `Axiom` (which technically mean the same thing but you can use to informally distinguish between concepts and facts).

```
Parameter set : Type.
Parameter elem : set -> set -> Prop.

Axiom set_extensionality : forall x y, (forall z, elem z x <-> elem z y) -> x = y.
(* etc. *)
```

In comparison, `Definition` and `Theorem` are used for defining and proving things. Having postulated the ZFC axioms, you can prove that a set is not an element of itself. The `Theorem` command takes a theorem name first (used to refer to it in the future):

```
Theorem no_self_elem : forall x, ~ elem x x.
Proof.
  (* tactics here. *)
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you very much!